# Prevent intellisense from complaining about dnx451 when targeting core50

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Code complains that:

> The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'...

[image: The intellisense is targeting 451.]

This is our project.json file.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandardapp1.5": {
            "imports": [
                "dnxcore50"
            ],
            "dependencies": {
                "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is our `dotnet build` output.

```
> dotnet build
Compiling VsCodeIntellisense for .NETStandardApp,Version=v1.5

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.5669579
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the most resent version of vscode appears to have fixed this.